# JSON parse returns null

Tags: ios, json, cocoa, ios5

i need to parse the Apple JSON but i have a little problem. I'm now doing this:

The problem is here:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                         options:kNilOptions 
                                                           error:&error];



    NSNumber *resultCount = [json objectForKey:@"resultCount"];
    NSLog(@"%i", [resultCount intValue]);

    NSArray * AppStoreUrlParse = [json objectForKey:@"results"]; 

    NSDictionary* StoreParse = [AppStoreUrlParse objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"%@", [json objectForKey:@"price"]);

}
```

On this line:

```
    NSLog(@"%i", [resultCount intValue]);
```

The NSlog is returing: 1 like in the JSON ( http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=387633954)

But on this line

```
    NSLog(@"%@", [json objectForKey:@"price"]);
```

The NSLOG returns (Null)

does anyone know how i can get the price from the json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that 'price' is part of a dictionary that is the first item in the 'results' array.

Can you try

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[AppStoreUrlParse objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"price"]);
```

This would get the value of the key 'price' in the first element of the 'results' array of your JSON.

**EDIT**

Actually, rereading your code, you are already getting the first element of the array in this line:

```
NSDictionary* StoreParse = [AppStoreUrlParse objectAtIndex:0];
```

So all you need to do is change `json` by `StoreParse` in your NSLog:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [StoreParse objectForKey:@"price"]);
```